# Can I install GD library with php 7.2?

Tags: php, gd, yum

I installed `php72-php-gd`, `php70-php-gd`, `2 php-gd` in Amazon Linux 2 AMI server with

```
yum install php72-g
```

I can't get any information about GD library in php.info, the old server was Ubuntu 16.04.3 from DigitalOcean and works well there.

Comment: Did you restart php-fpm and/or apache?

Comment: That's it, I just found the solution with restart sudo systemctl restart php-fpm.service
Thanks @Jerodev

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 7):

```
apt-get install php7.2-gd
```

works for me on Debian Stretch with this php7.2 packages [php7.2 install](https://pratt.is/php-7-2-unter-debian-9/)

you have to know the name of the package you need, it differs from distro to distro and install it.

Comment: not working
`E: Unable to locate package php7.2-gd
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-gd'`

Comment: that looks like to depend on: the php version has now changed and php7.2 packages where out ranged, you simply have to install the actually php packages maybe php7.4-gd for ubuntu, at this time.
Or php7.3-gd for debian buster at this time.
https://packages.debian.org/buster/php-gd

Answer (score 1):

Gd library don't work on wampserver with php 7.2.10